# Power BI - Switch table structure depending on what is selected

Tags: report, visualization, powerbi

I'm trying to understand the workflow and how to think when working with Power BI.

I'm trying to create the visual side of a logging framework using azure application insights and log analytics in the background.

What I got stuck on right now is using a visualization for different table structures.

**Scenario:**

So lets say I have an integration workflow that is compiled of different components (starts at one endpoint, being processed and sent to destination endpoint), and this workflow is used in parallel depending on the endpoints.

Visualization:

```
A ----> (integration process) -----> B
C ----> (integration process) -----> D

A <---- (integration process) <----- B
C <---- (integration process) <----- D
```

In this process I'm logging traces and exceptions for each workflow for example.

And lets say I have extracted the power BI query from log analytics to import the data into Power BI.

Now as you can see above I have an "Send" and "Receive" flow for both sets of endpoints per parallel integration so to speak and I want to be able to pair these per report in Power BI.

**Problem:**

So then to my problem for now;

Let's say I want to put a doughnut chart with total amount sent AND received messages.

Also when clicking on the different parts of the chart I want to change the containing data and also the structure of the single table in the same report.

What I'm struggling with is using a table to display the content of two workflows that are related to each other in the sense of being a "Sent and received" visualization of the integration, but don't have any hard drawn relations to each other in code.

I was reading something about a switch statement but I thought i'd ask the question here to learn "the way of thinking" when using Power BI.

[image]

Hope I made my problem clear by the description above, if I forgot anything please ask and I'll do my best to try to further explain what I'm asking for.

**EDIT**:

Ok so regarding the feedback i got of the question being to broad, does it help i i would say i want to be able to switch everything in a Table (that is: all columns and values), by a clickable slicer for example.

why i'm trying to achieve is something similar to this, but for a table view:

Youtube Link:
[Using SWITCH True Logic In Power BI - DAX Concepts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UsAJPIANAb8&t=71s)

Do i select the content of a table with a measure-query or do i have to do any other special fix to get this to work?

Hope this clarify the problem i'm working on.

Comment: This question is rather broad to be able to answer very well. There are things you can do with `SWITCH` functions and bookmarks, but an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would make this much more answerable.

Comment: I'll see if i can drill down to my core problem, thanks for taking the time reading the post though :)

Comment: @AlexisOlson hope this explains the problem a bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to switch between two entirely different tables, I'd recommend using buttons to toggle between different bookmarks which show/hide different visuals.

Check out the documentation for [bookmarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-bookmarks) and [buttons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-buttons) for more detailed information and come back if you get stuck and have more specific questions.

Comment: Thanks, i'll definitely check that out! :)

Comment: Ok so i found something related to what you said, and it worked like a charm.
A video explication can be found here done by "Guy in a Cube" on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Afcj8mT5_Q

Comment: But just a question before i mark it as the answer, is it possible to toggle the different bookmarks when clicking on a part of a pie-chart? That is using the responsiveness of the plugins instead of using a toggling picture? @AlexisOlson

Comment: I don't think you can tie bookmarks to pie chart selections at this time, unfortunately.

Comment: Aaahh too bad... that would've been perfect! :P well i have "toggle buttons" i guess. Thanks for the information! If anyone else know a way to tie chart-selections to bookmarks please write and update this post.

Comment: You (and future readers) may find this thread relevant as well: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Bookmark-on-slicer-selection/td-p/307164